# How to display image in another page as lightbox with zooming

Tags: jquery, html, image, magnific-popup

I'm new to Jquery. I have an image that needs to be opened in another tab with a magnifier. 
This opens in a new tab but I don't know to how to add a zoom lens to this image.

```
<a href="images/layout.jpg" ><img src="images/layout.jpg" /></a>
```

How can I do this?
**EDIT**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var totalImgs=$('img').length;

$('img').each(function(){
    var imgSel=$(this);
    var imgActualWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).wrap( "<div class='imgs'></div>" );
    var par=$(this).parent();
    par.css({'z-index':''+totalImgs+''});
    totalImgs=totalImgs-1;
    par.append("<div><span>+</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>-</span></div>");
    par.children('div').on('click','span:nth-child(1)',function(){
        imgSel.width(imgSel.width()+imgActualWidth);
    });
    par.children('div').on('click','span:nth-child(2)',function(){
        if(imgSel.width()>imgActualWidth)
        {
        imgSel.width(imgSel.width()-imgActualWidth);
        }
    });
});
    </script>
    <style>
        .imgs{
    position:relative;
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    z-index:100;
}
.imgs div{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:15px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.imgs div span{
    cursor:pointer;
}
        </style>


    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/course_layout.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please see this

Comment: Magnifier? do you mean Zoom-in & Zoom out plugin?

Comment: Yes zoom-in and zoom out. Sorry to use that word `magnifier`

Comment: If you're new to jQuery, it would probably be easier [to use a plugin](http://jdbartlett.com/loupe/)

Comment: Ok i will add an answer within 10 minutes

Comment: Ya sure zword..Waiting for you

Comment: [This has a lightbox gallery popup that can zoom](http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example3.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will have to open a page on clicking link:

```
<a href="images/pagecontainingimage.html" target="_blank" ><img src="images/layout.jpg" /></a>
```

Then use the code in the way it is used in the below fiddle:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/4zvfe/)

## Entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>
  <style type='text/css'>
    .imgs{
        position:relative;
        width:70px;
        height:70px;
        z-index:100;
    }
    .imgs div{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:15px;
        font-size:20px;
        color:red;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    .imgs div span{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function(){
    var totalImgs=$('img').length;

    $('img').each(function(){
        var imgSel=$(this);
        var imgActualWidth = $(this).width();
        $(this).wrap( "<div class='imgs'></div>" );
        var par=$(this).parent();
        par.css({'z-index':''+totalImgs+''});
        totalImgs=totalImgs-1;
        par.append("<div><span>+</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>-</span></div>");
        par.children('div').on('click','span:nth-child(1)',function(){
            imgSel.width(imgSel.width()+imgActualWidth);
        });
        par.children('div').on('click','span:nth-child(2)',function(){
            if(imgSel.width()>imgActualWidth)
            {
            imgSel.width(imgSel.width()-imgActualWidth);
            }
        });
    });
    });//]]>  

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <img src="images/course_layout.jpg"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you post more information of what you have tried along with more code?

Comment: I inserted the link to JQuery 1.10` <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`, then I included ur code. But when I click on the image, it opens up new tab but no zooming or zoom out

Comment: I tried something with feather.js, but there the zoomin and zoomout works only when I use firebug and not otherwise

Comment: Are you directly opening image?Use a page with the code used in the fiddle to show the image with zoom effect.Also use `http://` with the url : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have added it. Please check and tell me

Comment: @user3004356 i will add the entire code in my answer in 5 mins

Comment: Ya this works , but I nee to change that + and _ symbols with magnifier image. How can I do that.

Comment: As well is there anyway you know how to make the image at the center and make the background around the image semi-transparent, sorry I dont know what they say

Comment: replace + & - in this line with img tags: `par.append("<div><span>+</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>-</span></div>");`